# How to connect to a remote Mongo database with no proxy option?

Tags: mongodb, proxy, connection

Is there a way to prevent the use of proxies while using MongoCLI ? 
I'm working in an environment with defined HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY and mongodb is using this as default path.

How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it two ways

```
unset HTTP_PROXY
unset HTTPS_PROXY
mongo
```

or

```
HTTP_PROXY= HTTPS_PROXY= mongo
```

Comment: I did it with `export HTTP_PROXY=''` , but I'd rather prevent it directly from mongo-cli

Comment: @awzx, I hope your query is resolved? If you want to protect just once command you can even do an alias. `alias mongocli=HTTP_PROXY= HTTPS_PROXY= mongo'`. This will prevent your from typing it again and again

Comment: actually it didn't work this way. I'm still unable to connect disabling the env variables, and I'd rather disable the proxy on runtime instead than disabling it onto system.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some Linux OSes need a semi-colon (;) before the command when setting variables before a command like, so sometimes I have to try this to get inline variable definition to work:
`HTTP_PROXY= HTTPS_PROXY= http_proxy= https_proxy=; mongo`

Also, it might be because the lower case versions of the proxy are set, so disabling those too, right before the command may help.   Try the above with or without the semi-colon.

Alternatively, you can add your dbhost name to no_proxy and NO_PROXY environment variables:
`export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,<DB_HOSTNAME>,<.domain.local>`
where <DB_HOSTNAME> is replaced by your db server names, or a pattern that will match all of them.  I included the <.domain.local> to indicate matching against the domainname....   so if all of your db hostnames have a domain at the end, that's another way to get NO_PROXY to match.

Here is some relevant documentation that can assist with bot potential answers:
[MongoDB mongocli environment variables](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongocli/stable/configure/environment-variables/)